# How to create an embedded document that follows a model with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models, `Post` and `Comment`:

My `Post` model (`models/post.js`):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Comment = require('../models/comment');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', new Schema({
    text: {type: String, trim: true},
    postedBy: String,
    comments: [Comment]
}));
```

My `Comment` model (`models/comment.js`):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', new Schema({
    user: String,
    comment: {type: String, trim: true},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now(), select: false}
}));
```

When I attempt to create a new post without any `comments`, the post is created perfectly fine.

Although when I try to `$push` a comment to the post after creation, nothing happens.

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"_id": req.params.id}, 
    {$push: {comments: {
        comment: "Hello World",
        user: "933ujrfn393r"
    }}
}).exec(function(err, post) {
    console.log(post);
    res.json({success: true});
});
```

Why is this failing to push the comment to the post? My `console.log(post)` line simply logs `undefined`, so not too sure what is happening here. I tried a simple test of `Post.findOne({"_id": req.params.id})` and it returned the post successfully, so there is no problem with the find query.

Comment: Instead of using two different collections for this, use single collection and in that collection you can separately define schema for the field comments.

Answer (score 13):

#### Embedded sub documents

Your usage implies an embedded [sub document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) inside the model which only requires a [schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) definition for the sub document. This will store both schema's in a single document in a single collection in MongoDB

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
    user: String,
    comment: {type: String, trim: true},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now(), select: false}
});

var PostSchema = new Schema({
    text: {type: String, trim: true},
    postedBy: String,
    comments: [CommentSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Then create comments as you were.

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
    {"_id": req.params.id}, 
    {$push: {comments: {
        comment: "Hello World",
        user: "933ujrfn393r"
    }}
}).then(function (post) {
    console.log(post);
    res.json({success: true});
});
```

#### Document references

If you want to keep the two models then you would need to use a reference in your `Post` schema instead. This will create seperate documents in seperate collections in MongoDB and use the `_id` to look up the second document.

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
    text: {type: String, trim: true},
    postedBy: String,
    comments: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'Comment'
    }
});
```

Then comments need to be created before you can reference them in the `Post` model.

```
c = new Comment({ comment: 'x' })
c.save().then(function (result) {
  return Post.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    { $push: { comments: result._id } }
  );
}).then(function (result) {
  console.log('updated post');
});
```

[Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) can be used to easily retrieve the "foreign" documents.

Comment: If using the first method you mention (different models for each, although same document), how would I save the comment to the post document? I have tried creating the new comment like `c = new Comment({ comment: 'x' })` and then `$push`ing to the `Post`, although it doesn't seem to push anything...

Comment: `new Comment` is only for the second method where `Comment` is a model. When comments are just a Schema and embedded documents, the query should work as you have in your question.  Note that schema's and models are separate things in Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752897/adding-child-document-to-existing-mongodb-document), I believe your problem is that you're embedding the `Comment` **Model** instead of the `Comment` **Schema**.

Try changing `post.js` from:

`var Comment = require('../models/comment');`

to:

`var Comment = require('../models/comment').schema;`

This also makes sense after looking at the example on the Mongoose [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) regarding sub-docs.

P.S.
What helped me investigate this was outputting the `err` object of the `exec` callback to see what was actually going on...

Comment: That would work but creating a model also creates a separate collection in the database. If you are not using the model, then there's no point instantiating the model from the schema in the first place.